# Pandas Dataframe Python | How to compare a cell with another cell of a copied dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have 2 same dataframes with different names (df_1 and df_2).

Lets say the dataframes have 2 columns Category and Time.
For eg.

| Category | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2020-02-02 05:05:05.0000 |
| A | 2020-02-02 06:06:06.0000 |
| A | 2020-02-02 07:07:07.0000 |
| B | 2020-02-02 05:05:05.0000 |
| B | 2020-02-02 06:06:06.0000 |
| C | 2020-02-02 05:05:05.0000 |
| C | 2020-02-02 06:06:06.0000 |

I want the following if conditions:
if category of df_1 matches with category of df_2 then, in a new dataframe(with columns: category, starttime, endtime), In case of A category, I want to put the first datetime(2020-02-02 05:05:05.0000) in starttime and last datetime (2020-02-02 07:07:07.0000) in endtime column.

Final Result new dataframe:

| Category | Start Time | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-02-02 05:05:05.0000 | 2020-02-02 07:07:07.0000 |
| B | 2020-02-02 05:05:05.0000 | 2020-02-02 06:06:06.0000 |
| C | 2020-02-02 05:05:05.0000 | 2020-02-02 06:06:06.0000 |

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution for the original answer

```
pd.concat([df_1.groupby("CATEGORY").agg([min, max]),
           df_2.groupby("CATEGORY").agg([min, max])], 
        join="inner", axis=1).apply([min, max], axis=1)
    .rename(columns={"min":"START TIME", "max":"END TIME"})
```

### Explanation

1. First, you group each DataFrame by CATEGORY to keep the min and max of each of its value. This will also set the index to CATEGORY.

   ```
   grouped_1 = df_1.groupby("CATEGORY").agg([min, max])
   grouped_2 = df_2.groupby("CATEGORY").agg([min, max])
   ```
2. Then, you do an inner join to keep only the CATEGORies that are in both df_1 and df_2. By default, the inner join is done on the index, which is what we want here (column CATEGORY in our original DataFrames). You concatenate horizontally, getting 4 columns : two min and two max values per row.

   ```
   grouped_both = pd.concat([grouped_1, grouped_2], join="inner", axis=1)
   ```
3. You keep the min and max values of each row, and rename the columns.

   ```
   final_df = grouped_both.apply([min, max], axis=1)
       .rename(columns={"min":"START TIME", "max":"END TIME"})
   ```

NOTE : I assumed you wanted to merge the first and last timestamps of both DataFrames.
If you truly wanted the start from df_1 and end from df_2, it would be a slightly different solution.

## Solution for one DataFrame and adding duration

If I understood correctly, then you don't need to copy the original DataFrame.

```
# Group the DataFrame by CATEGORY and keep the min and max values
# We also need to get rid of the newly created MultiIndex level "TIME"
joined_df = df_1.groupby("CATEGORY").agg([min, max])["TIME"]
# Keep only rows where the min is different than the max
joined_df = joined_df[joined_df["min"]!= joined_df["max"]]
# Calculate the time deltas between min and max
# then cast it to a number value of the minutes
joined_df["DURATION"] = (joined_df[ "max"]- joined_df["min"]).astype('timedelta64[m]')
# We rename the columns min and max
joined_df = joined_df.rename(columns={"min":"START TIME", "max":"END TIME"})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes things very easy in few steps without for loops and if conditions. Is there a way to add another column (Duration in minutes), difference of timestamps?

My approach:

The '2 same dataframes' are actually one dataframe and another one is copied(df_1.copy()). The purpose for this was to get the first time stamp from one and last from another. Then,  in a new data frame check if a category entry exists or not, if it does not exist then populate the new dataframe with that row of df_1 else replace end time with the current time stamp of the that iteration from df_2.

Comment: I just edited my answer. I am not sure that it correctly addresses the needs in your comment, so please let me know.

Comment: This answers my question perfectly! Thanks a bunch.